# linq-to-sql grouping anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table the contains appointments. These appointments have different statuses (byte from 1 to 5) and dates; the column for the date is simply called `AppointDate`. I pass in a list of IDs and I want to group the result based on the status AND whether the date of the appointment is past or not.

`TheIDs` is a list of longs that's passed in as the parameter. This is what I have so far:

```
var TheCounterInDB = (from a in MyDC.Appointments
                      where TheIDs.Contains(a.ID)
                      group a by a.AppointStatus into TheGroups
                      select new { 
                             TheStatus = TheGroups.Key,
                             TheTotalCount = TheGroups.Count(),
                             TheLateCount = ?,
                             ThePendingCount = ?
                      }).ToList();
```

Basically, I want `TheLateCount` to be the count of all the appointments where status is 1 AND the date is past and `ThePendingCount` to be the count where status is 1 AND the date is not past. My anonymous type is good to return the count of all the different statuses (that's where the `.Key` is) but I'm wondering how to best add the date requirement into the grouping.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Um, what database are you using?  It would probably be easier to simply create two views in your database, one which counts the late appointments and one which counts pending. That way, you could simply call the views (assuming you're using a database that supports this) and access the one row they return.

Comment: @Adam: what more would you need? I think it's all there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var TheCounterInDB = (from a in MyDC.Appointments
                      where TheIDs.Contains(a.ID)
                      group a by a.AppointStatus into TheGroups
                      select new { 
                             TheStatus = TheGroups.Key,
                             TheTotalCount = TheGroups.Count(),
                             TheLateCount = TheGroups.Count(x => x.AppointStatus == 1 && x.AppointDate < DateTime.Today),
                             ThePendingCount = TheGroups.Count(x => x.AppointStatus == 1 && x.AppointDate >= DateTime.Today)
                      }).ToList();
```